# finding the number of non-appearing integers in three different sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

English,Math and Science classes started on the very first day of a month.Mathematics class schedule is 1,3,5,7,9. . . . The schedule for English is 1,4,7,10,13. . . And for Science is 1,5,9,13,17. . .In the next three months how many days will there be no classes of the above subjects?

I first tried to find the number of odd integers between 0 and 181 including the latter and argued that the same odd numbers will appear in the next two pattern sequences but of couse there will be a few more odd numbers.I tried to do some tedious calculation and have ended up with nothing.Then I tried to see the pattern between the digits that are not appearing  but that did not help either. A prod in the right direction would help at this stage,I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: try looking at the sequences in modulo $12$. You will find that certain values $\mod 12$ will not be in any sequence.

Comment: Thanks,I was looking mod 30 but now it seems obvious that i should have chosen 12